# How to add the GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC to InputStream

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, gzip

I am having an application in Angular/Spring Boot and I need to compress the body  from Angular to Spring Boot.
I compress the request in Angular with pako or Zlib on the Client side, and I am reading the request on the Server Side with java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream. As the compressed request doesn't have the GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC the java.util.zip library can't read the request.

How can I insert GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC in InputStream